# How do I initialize and test my queue that uses a struct in C?

Tags: c, queue

Hi I'm new to learning C (coming from java). I've written a `queue.c`, but I'm not sure how to test it in my main() function. My main problem is that I'm just not familiar with the syntax (i.e. how do I initialize the queue? how do I enq/deq from it and the format to print out the solution). Here is the code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_QUEUE_SIZE 100;

typedef struct queue {
    int queue[MAX_QUEUE_SIZE];
    int currSize;
    int head;
    int tail;
} queue;

void initQueue(queue *queue) {
    queue->currSize = 0;
    queue->pos = 0;
    queue->head = 0;
    queue->tail = 0;
}

void enqueue(queue *queue, int e) {
    if (isFull()) printf("Queue is full!");

    queue->queue[queue->tail] = e;
    queue->tail = (queue->tail + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE;
    q->currSize = q->currSize + 1;
}

int dequeue(queue *queue) {
    if (isEmpty()) printf("Queue is empty!");

    int toDequeue = queue->head;
    queue->head = (queue->head + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE;
    q->currSize = q->currSize - 1;

    return toDequeue;
}

int isEmpty(queue *queue) {
    return (queue->head == queue->tail);
}

int isFull(queue *queue) {
    return (currSize == MAX_QUEUE_SIZE);
}

int main() {
    /* how do I initialize the queue and enq/deq to test? */
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you want to test it, just create your queue on the stack and then start calling function.

```
int main()
{
 queue q;
initqueue(&q);
enqueue(&q, 1);
enqueue(&q, 2);
}
```

or, allocate it on the heap:

```
int main()
{
 queue *q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
 assert(q != NULL);
 initqueue(q);
 enqueue(q, 1);
 enqueue(q, 2);
}
```

Also note that you will likely run into troubles because you use a type name as a variable name.

Comment: thanks! I was going to add generics to it next. But just for testing integers it should be fine, right?

Comment: @Ermias Asghedom New to C, you will need understand pointer to understand above code.

Comment: generics in C?, I would need to google to sure myself.

Comment: Yeah it will work in both case -- but since your queue size is fixed, be careful its not too big to exhaust the stack (it likely wont be). Also as pmverma said, if you're not familiar with pointer, go read about them before going further. They are extremely important to C. As for generic in C, well, you can work around it with `void *`, but it's not very friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding for GNU/Linux or any POSIX compliant OS, you should consider using the Sys V Message Que or named or unnamed pipes as Que. See man pages for  msgsnd(), msgrcv(), popen(), read(), write(), pclose(), pipe().

In Java you would have avoided creating you own Que class and instead used inbuilt Que Class of Java. Likewise it would be best to use msq que or named/unnamed pipes as Que instead of malloc()ing and managing them in your code.